# Exibindo resultado completo do Fractions

Tags: python-3.x

Estou gerando simplificações de números através do pacote Fractions.

Tudo certo até encontrar números em que a simplificação vai até o máximo, ou seja, reduzindo um dos termos a "1".

Quando isso acontece o programa omite esse valor, exibindo somente o outro. Por exemplo:

```
import fractions as F
print(F.Fraction(723520/51680))
```

Irá gerar a saída `14` e não `14/1` como deveria ser e como a [própria documentação do pacote mostra que era para ocorrer.](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) Exemplo **`Fraction(123)`** da documentação.

---

[link no IdeOne](https://ideone.com/9ehv5K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os exemplos da documentação exibem os resultados direto do terminal interativo do Python e esses exibem a representação do objeto, isto é, o retorno do método `__repr__`, através da função `repr()`. Assim, para atingir o mesmo resultado, você terá que fazer:

```
print(repr(Fraction(723520/51680)))
```

Isso pois a função `print()` invoca internamente o método `__str__` do objeto, que produz o resultado escalar, 14. Se deseja acessar os valores do numerador e denominador como inteiros, basta acessar os campos `numerator` e `denominator` do objeto `Fraction`, respectivamente. Veja um exemplo:

```
from fractions import Fraction

f = Fraction(723520/51680)

print('str(f) =', f)
print('repr(f) =', repr(f))

# Acessando numerador e denominador

print('Numerador:', f.numerator)
print('Denominador:', f.denominator)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SpatialWoefulEmacs) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/lUBuiF)</sup>

Documentação oficial: [9.5. fractions — Rational numbers](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html)

Comment: Obrigado, Anderson. O resultado é gerado como um tipo `list`, correto? Nesse caso precisei fazer um split e depois strip para exibir somente os números. Funcionou, mas não ficou muito Pythônico. Não tem como gerá-los em int? Obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: @Max Não, o resultado é uma *string*. Existe uma maneira muito mais fácil que adicionei na resposta para acessar os valores do numerador e denominador como inteiros.